# Bash script to open browser and log specific data

Tags: bash, shell, logging, browser

I am trying to write a bash script that will open up the default browser, connect to a pre-defined address and log the website's IP address and browser name into a log file.
I have no idea where to start from, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "the website's browser name"?

Comment: And why do you want to start a browser when all you log is the IP address the domain name resolves to? Isn't a simple DNS lookup enough then?

Comment: i have a command that opens a specific website. i want to identify the browser in different computer that open when i run the script. such as chrome, ie, etc.